# Change Output Result date/time format of Oracle Query with Visual Studio Code

Tags: oracle, formatting, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using Visual Studio Code ( Version  1.59.0 ) with Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code as Extension and i want to change the output results .
Currently , with Oracle SQL Developer (  Version 20.4.1.407 ) I have the following results for dates :

[Format 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3o0M.png)

[Format 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoCkP.png)

Where, at my VS Code, the output for the same query return as :

[Format 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOAH0.png)

[Format 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A0ll.png)

My system format date does not equals to the output ( and that is ok, not a problem here , but also, not a solution ).

So, what i need to do or go to have an option to change the output result format for the date and time ? =)

Thank you all =)

Answer (score 2):

Before you issue the query (in the same session) issue ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='your_date_format_here'

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html#GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A

At some point we plan to add a feature to automatically execute commands like this with each session that is established (eg via a login.sql file or similar), but for now you will need to do it yourself or use a login trigger (if you are reading this post in the future, check for the login.sql feature first).

Comment: Christian, thank you so much for the replay ! 
Meanwhile, i did tried that solution, even when the output says that the session has been changed, the output stays the same.

Comment: Can you please provide the ALTER SESSION command you are issuing? Also try the alter session  command in  sql*plus and make sure it works there too. Finally, let me know what version of the extension you are using. This did NOT work in an older version.

Comment: Sure i can provide that information! 
This is the code that i issue before the session : 
`ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD'` ---

VS Studio : 1.63.2
Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code : 21.3.0

Comment: Sorry, adding more information since i can't edit my first comment. 
`ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD'` ---

VS Studio : 1.63.2 //
Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code : 21.3.0 // 

This happens only on VS Code,  even with the Oracle SQL Dev and on another base  ( SQL , with Azure Data Studio ) the output format matchs the Oracle ( my first image ) .

Comment: Strange. It works for me.. if I execute: ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD'; select hire_date from employees; The results window uses that date format, eg "2001-01-13"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Christian Shay's answer, and running ALTER SESSION along with the query did work. I did want to add that highlight that timedate can be included as well.

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss';
```